# How do i replace fscanf with a function from the libsndfile library?

Tags: c

I opened wav file with libsndfile library and want to read through this file and get N number of points in FFT and get time-domain samples and calculate FFT.

any ideas how I could replace fscanf with function from libsndfile library? 
here is line of code:

```
for(i=0; i < N; i++) fscanf(fs, "%lg%lg", &x[i][0], &x[i][1]);
```

So, problem is I don't know how to work with wav. without libsndfile and how to implement some things using libsndfile.

thanks,
a.

Comment: I opened wav file with libsndfile library and want to read through this file and get N number of points in FFT and get time-domain samples and calculate FFT. So, don't know how to do this without libsndfile and don't know how to implement some things using libsndfile..

Comment: ok, so ask for that. please edit your question so that it explains exactly what you're trying to do, with what you already have regarding the .wav file operations, and what you're failing at.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you want to replace fscanf, rather than write your own function with a different name, and use it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want to read N samples and then you do:

```
for(i=0; i < N; i++) fscanf(fs, "%lg%lg", &x[i][0], &x[i][1]);
```

so you're reading 2 * N samples and I'm not sure why.

If you grab the libsndfile source code tarball, there are example programs in the examples/ directory. Basically you do:

```
SNDFILE * sf ;
SF_INFO info ;
double  array [N] ;

memset (&info, 0, sizeof (info));
if ((sf = sf_open (filename, SFM_READ, &info)) == NULL)
   handle_error () ;

sf_read_double (sf, array, N) ;
sf_close (sf) ;
```

This code assumes you file is mono (only one channel).

Comment: andrey, you should accept or at least upvote Erik's answer as it is much more thorough than mine.  Also because he is the creator of libsndfile he probably deserves the kudos more than me :)

Comment: Yes, both answers are really helpful and it's hard to choose,u know :-) I like Audacity's ImportPCM.cpp code - there is a lot of usable things. Thats the reason why I accepted yours.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the file with `sf_open`, then read the file with `sf_read_float` to get the samples back.

You can do this N times in your for loop and to write to an array and then send that off to your fft.

Source: libsndfile api
http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html

Also you may want to check Audacity's ImportPCM.cpp for a concrete example.